# How can I Bulk Insert Images in Google Sheet from Images Blobs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

**Greetings Folks!**

I post to the community from time-to-time when I come across issues/limitations with apps script. It helps me and both the community to share ideas that other can use for future references.

Being an apps script developer, I am working on tasks to grab images from internet and set them as cell values in a column. I know about the `=IMAGE(source,  alt_text, height, width)` formula and have good knowledge of how to set formulas in cells using apps script.

The task I am working on has a portion of code that looks like following:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const imagesURLs = sheet.getRange('B2:B1000').getValues().map((link) => { return link[0] };
const responses = URLFetchApp.fetchAll(imagesURLs);

responses.forEach((response, ind) => {
    const image = response.getBlob();
    sheet.insertImage(image, 1, index + 2,  20,  60).setHeight(50).setWidth(50);
});
```

The above solution is working and at the end I get all 999 images fetched from the links and placed in the column A of my Google Sheet.

The only problem I am facing now is that this happen very slowly (25 to 30 minutes), instead of looking through the blobs and setting images in cells one-by-one, I want to convert this into batch operation, something like this:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const imagesURLs = sheet.getRange('B2:B1000').getValues().map((link) => { return link[0] };
const blobs = URLFetchApp.fetchAll(imagesURLs).map((response) =>{
    return response.getBlob();
});

sheet.getRange('A2:A1000').insertImages(blobs); // unfortunately this is not possible
```

But it's not possible to set images as bulk in range like we do `setValues(values)` on a range. I did search online and didn't find anyone who overcome this issue. Will really appreciate suggestions and ideas on this.

Note: I need the image in cell as cell content and not a formula

Comment: I am open to use the advance Sheets API V4 or external libraries (if there is a solution you have in mind).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Sheets API V4 won't do it, according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43665027

Comment: Have you experimented with using the CellImage class?  You could make multiple calls to [`SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newCellImage()), and then call `setValues` just once with an array of CellImages; I'm not sure if this will improve performance though.

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee, I appreciate your response. I did try to create `cellImageBuilderArray ` for all the image urls, but `range.setvalues(cellImageBuilderArr)` takes the same amount of time.